# java.util.logging.Logger shows multiple times after loop

Tags: java

I have for loop that after block close , cull logger to show some log but don't know what happening here after this it's call every time for loop have length , It's weird!
in this case the

**NOTE : IF use System.out.println();
its work fine and show one time.

```
log.log(Level.INFO , "Translated Setences from "+countOfTranslated+" / "+sentenses.size()+" successfully");
```

is after the for loop block close and it doesn't make any sense.
if some one know something share.
look at my full code :

```
package mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp;


import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentCoreAnnotations;

import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.instagram.Application;
import mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.instagram.repository.RepositoryTranslate;
import mehritco.ir.megnatis.tools.file.BasicLocation;


import java.util.*;

/**
 * https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/human-languages.html
 * https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/models.html
 * @author Megnatis
 *
 */
public class TextAnalyzer {
    public static String unTranslatedText = """
    درما در اینجا هستیم . سلام خوبی؟ وقت بخیر چیکار میکنی
تسلیت 
راستی یادت نره بیای . دوست دارم عزیزم
چه میشه کرد؟
اونجایی
            """;
    
    /**
     * @link https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ssplit.html#sentence-splitting-from-java
     * @param paragraph Max-length is 1024 byte 
     * @return
     */
    public static ArrayList<String> breakParagraphToSentence(String paragraph){
        ArrayList<String> sentenses = new ArrayList<String>();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        
         props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");
         /**
             * @Link https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ssplit.html#options
             * Whether to treat newlines as sentence breaks. This property has 3 legal values.
             * “always” means that a newline is always a sentence break
             * (but there still may be multiple sentences per line).
             */
         props.setProperty("ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak", "always");
            /**
             * @link https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html
             * Java character offsets (stored in the CharacterOffset{Begin,End}Annotation) 
             * are in terms of 16-bit char’s, with Unicode characters outside the basic 
             * multilingual prime encoded as two chars via a surrogate pair.
             * if need emoji use true .
             */
         props.setProperty("tokenize.codepoint", "true");
         
         StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
         CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(paragraph);
            pipeline.annotate(document);
            for (CoreSentence sentence : document.sentences()) {
                sentenses.add(sentence.text());//split sentence with newLine char
            }
        return sentenses;
    }
    /**
     * For create Paragraph from TranslatedText
     * @param sentenses
     * @param log
     * @return String translated Paragraph
     */
    @Nullable
    public static String getParagraphInTranslated(ArrayList<String> sentenses , Logger log) {
        //Check null sentence or not
                if(sentenses == null || sentenses.size() < 0 || sentenses.isEmpty()) {
                    return null ;
                }
                String allSentenceToGetter = "";
                int countOfTranslated = 0;
                for (String sentense : sentenses) {
                      RepositoryTranslate repositoryTranslate = new RepositoryTranslate();
                      Logger logger = Application.setupLog(BasicLocation.getBaseFileDir()+"logs");
                      JSONObject translateJson =  repositoryTranslate.translate(sentense, "fa", "en", logger);
                      boolean isTranslated = translateJson.optBoolean(RepositoryTranslate.IS_TRANSLATE);
                      if(isTranslated) {
                          String textFromTranslate = translateJson.optString(RepositoryTranslate.TRANSLATE_TEXT);
                          allSentenceToGetter += (textFromTranslate+"\n") ;
                          countOfTranslated++;
                      }
                }
                
                log.log(Level.INFO , "Translated Setences from "+countOfTranslated+" / "+sentenses.size()+" successfully");
                return allSentenceToGetter;
    }
    /**
     * @param sentenses Use breakParagraphToSentence() to get input
     */
    public static void analyzer(ArrayList<String> sens , Logger log) {
        String paragraphTranslated = null;
        //Check null sentence or not
        if(sens == null || sens.size() < 0 || sens.isEmpty()) {
            return ;
        }else {
            paragraphTranslated = getParagraphInTranslated(sens, log);
        }
        if(paragraphTranslated == null) {
            return;
        }
         Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment");
         properties.setProperty("ssplit.newlineIsSentenceBreak", "always");
         properties.setProperty("tokenize.codepoint", "true");
         StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
        
         Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(paragraphTranslated);
            List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

           // sentences
            for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
              String sentiment = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.SentimentClass.class);
              System.out.println(sentiment + "\t" + sentence);
            }
            //Tokenizing process https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokenize.html
            CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument(unTranslatedText);
            pipeline.annotate(doc);
//          for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
//            // Get the parse tree for each sentence
//            Tree parseTree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
//            // Do something interesting with the parse tree!
//            System.out.println(parseTree);
//          }
            for (CoreLabel tok : doc.tokens()) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s\t%d\t%d", tok.word(), tok.beginPosition(), tok.endPosition()));
              }
        
    }
    
    

      public static void main(String[] args)  {
          Logger logger = Application.setupLog(BasicLocation.getBaseFileDir()+"logs");
          analyzer(breakParagraphToSentence(unTranslatedText), logger);


        }

    }
```

the output is :

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.140 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.150 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.155 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.162 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.167 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.172 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.177 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.182 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.7 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.7 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator sentiment
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentModel - Loading sentiment model edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz ... done [0.1 sec].
Neutral We are here.
Neutral Hi how are you?
Neutral Good morning, what are you doing?
Neutral condolences
Negative    I really do not remember.
Positive    I love you baby
Neutral What can be done?
Neutral There
درما    1   5
در  6   8
اینجا   9   14
هستیم   15  20
.   21  22
سلام    23  27
خوبی    28  32
؟   32  33
وقت 34  37
بخیر    38  42
چیکار   43  48
میکنی   49  54
تسلیت   55  60
راستی   61  66
یادت    67  71
نره 72  75
بیای    76  80
.   81  82
دوست    83  87
دارم    88  92
عزیزم   93  98
چه  99  101
میشه    102 106
کرد 107 110
؟   110 111
اونجایی 112 119
```

The Output I Except must show like this :

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
 -> 2022/05/04 07:40:47.140 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
successfully
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.7 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [0.7 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator sentiment
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentModel - Loading sentiment model edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz ... done [0.1 sec].
Neutral We are here.
Neutral Hi how are you?
Neutral Good morning, what are you doing?
Neutral condolences
Negative    I really do not remember.
Positive    I love you baby
Neutral What can be done?
Neutral There
درما    1   5
در  6   8
اینجا   9   14
هستیم   15  20
.   21  22
سلام    23  27
خوبی    28  32
؟   32  33
وقت 34  37
بخیر    38  42
چیکار   43  48
میکنی   49  54
تسلیت   55  60
راستی   61  66
یادت    67  71
نره 72  75
بیای    76  80
.   81  82
دوست    83  87
دارم    88  92
عزیزم   93  98
چه  99  101
میشه    102 106
کرد 107 110
؟   110 111
اونجایی 112 119
```

As if you need setupLog method:

```
    public static Logger setupLog(String pathForSqlite) {
        Logger logger;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        // Addressing your comment:
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        String prefix = sdf.format(date);
        File logPath = new File(pathForSqlite);
        if (!logPath.exists()) {
            logPath.mkdir();
        }
        String dataBaseName = "Reflex_log_" + prefix + "_.db";
        logger = Logger.getLogger(APP_NAME);
        Connection connection = new SqliteConnection(pathForSqlite, dataBaseName).getConnection();
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        logger.setLevel(defaultLogLevel);
        LogFormatterSqlite formatter = new LogFormatterSqlite(connection);
        ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        handler.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.addHandler(handler);
        return logger;
    }
```

After Read Comments and some investigation , Added some lines and here the result :

Code :

```
@Nullable
    public static String getParagraphInTranslated(ArrayList<String> sentenses , Logger log) {
        //Check null sentence or not
                if(sentenses == null || sentenses.size() < 0 || sentenses.isEmpty()) {
                    return null ;
                }
                String allSentenceToGetter = "";
                int countOfTranslated = 0;
                log.log(Level.INFO , "JUST FOR CHECK");
                for (String sentense : sentenses) {
                      RepositoryTranslate repositoryTranslate = new RepositoryTranslate();
                      Logger logger = Application.setupLog(BasicLocation.getBaseFileDir()+"logs");
                      JSONObject translateJson =  repositoryTranslate.translate(sentense, "fa", "en", logger);
                      boolean isTranslated = translateJson.optBoolean(RepositoryTranslate.IS_TRANSLATE);
                      if(isTranslated) {
                          String textFromTranslate = translateJson.optString(RepositoryTranslate.TRANSLATE_TEXT);
                          textFromTranslate = textFromTranslate.trim();
                          allSentenceToGetter += (textFromTranslate+"\n") ;
                          countOfTranslated++;
                      }
                }
                log.log(Level.INFO , "JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue");
                log.log(Level.INFO , "Translated Setences from "+countOfTranslated+" / "+sentenses.size()+" successfully");
                log.log(Level.INFO , "JUST FOR CHECK After Issue");
                return allSentenceToGetter;
    }
```

Result :

```
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.767 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :0) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.833 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.840 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.845 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.851 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.857 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.864 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.869 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.875 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :1) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK Before Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.880 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.885 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.891 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.896 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.901 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.907 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.912 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.917 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :2) ]  : Translated Setences from 7 / 7 successfully
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.922 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.927 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.932 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.937 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.958 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.963 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.968 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
 -> 2022/05/04 09:25:34.973 {INFO} [mehritco.ir.megnatis.institute.reflex.nlp.TextAnalyzer At Method :getParagraphInTranslated (Line :3) ]  : JUST FOR CHECK After Issue
```

Comment: Are you sure that the following line of code should be **inside** the `for` loop (in method `getParagraphInTranslated`): `Logger logger = Application.setupLog(BasicLocation.getBaseFileDir()+"logs");`

Comment: I don't want to be in loop , I want show result after the excute method in one line

Comment: @Abra nope it's just setup Log and formatted , anywhere i use this and result as i except but in this time Idk what happening here

Comment: @Abra I think its a bug in logger with corenlp(that have logger insided)

Comment: I'd suggest debugging (i.e. stepping through your code). Given that each log message has a different timestamp, it looks like it's getting invoked multiple times.  Do you have a log config?  Probably would be called logging.properties somewhere.  I'm not familiar with JUL, but in other logging frameworks, with certain configs you can have one invocation lead to several messages getting printed.  Given the different timestamps this is unlikely, though.

Comment: @Taylor I do it and test with System.out.print everthing work fine and with print method shows only one time , in breakpoint nothing found that can be weird

Comment: and do you have logging config somewhere?

Comment: I'd suggest temporarily disabling the the sql logging.  That time difference between log printings is odd, you've got ~40 ms between the first and last logged statements in your first sample output.  That's a VERY long time for 7 log statements.  I wonder if some interaction with the sql logging is causing a retry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've called `setupLog` 7 times.  Each time you get the logger

```
        logger = Logger.getLogger(APP_NAME);
```

then add a new handler

```
        logger.addHandler(handler);
```

By the time you log something, the logger has 7 handlers all doing the same thing, so naturally all 7 handlers print out whatever message you ask the logger to output.

The solution is to move `setupLog` to the start of the program, or at least outside of any routine which might loop like this.  It's pretty bad separation of concerns to set up the logging in the same code path that does machine translation, anyway...

Comment: I think you miss understanding . this method create in one time . if you right so the line : log.log(Level.INFO , "JUST FOR CHECK"); appears 7 times not one time!

Comment: This analysis is obviously wrong. The "JUST FOR CHECK" line appears before you call `setupLog` an extra 7 times, so of course it doesn't get duplicated. You're already calling `setupLog` once in your `main()` function, so remove the redundant call in `analyzer()` and you will stop getting the extra logs.  If you simply try this, you will see this is the correct answer.

Comment: I found you right in for loop put Log Creator:                      RepositoryTranslate repositoryTranslate = new RepositoryTranslate();
                      Logger logger = Application.setupLog(BasicLocation.getBaseFileDir()+"logs");